# how to call ng-Click on on mdt-custom-cell attribue

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

```
        <mdt-custom-cell html-content="true" column-key="role">
        <!-- <span ng-class="{'red': value > 5, 'green': value <= 5}">    {{value}}</span> -->
         <button ng-click="showTabDialog($event)"  class="btn btn-success">Order Now </button>

    </mdt-custom-cell>
```

this is my html code for the material-data-table.My function is ..

```
     $scope.showTabDialog = function(ev) {
              console.log("hello");
                $mdDialog.show({
                controller: 'addToPrintListDialog',
                templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/addToPriceListDialog.html',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                targetEvent: ev,
                clickOutsideToClose:true
              })
          .then(function(answer) {
            $scope.status = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
          }, function() {
            $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
          });
      };
```

this is not working only for the custom cell. Is there any other alternative to get this working,if not by this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `clientScope.showTabDialog($event)` as stated [here](https://github.com/iamisti/mdDataTable/issues/174).